# Why does Function.x work after declaring Function.prototype.x?

Tags: javascript, prototype

As I understand it, a Function's prototype property is how you add methods/properties to all objects instantiated from that function.

So when I try something like this

```
function Person(){}
Person.prototype.saySomething = function(){ alert( "hi there" ); }

Person.saySomething();
```

I get the error "Person.saySomething is not a function", which makes sense as Im not executing the function on a Person object instance.

But why than does running the below code work?

```
Function.prototype.sayHi = function(){ alert( "hi!" );}

Function.sayHi();
```

Comment: You are probably just using this as an example, but it is worth noting that prototyping native objects is a bad idea.

Comment: I understand. Ive seen it in some frameworks and was wondering how it worked

Comment: @jbabey: When is it a bad idea? Always? I'd have to disagree.

Comment: @jbabey I don't agree at all.  This is one of the more powerful sides of the language when used with care.

Comment: @amnotiam you are right, my statement was a little too broad. here's a [decent article](http://perfectionkills.com/extending-built-in-native-objects-evil-or-not/)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to create an instance of `Person` first:

```
new Person().saySomeThing();
```

Prototype methods/properties are only inherit when an instance of the constructor is created, via the [`new`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/new) keyword.

`Function.sayHi()` works, because the `Function` constructor is **also** a function.

Comment: I couldn't think of why the `Function` example worked.  Good call, very clever.  If you really want to get confused, putting the `Person` constructor with the `Function` example, `Person.sayHi()` would work also...

Comment: Can you elaborate on "function constructor is also a function"? I understand your first point about instantiating it first, but why no "new" for the second one?

Comment: @levi I will try to explain it in simple words: `Function` can be considered as `function Function() { [native code] }`. Since all function instances (`function(){}`) inherit from `Function.prototype`, the `Function` constructor is also affected.  To verify that `Function` is indeed an instance of `Function`: **`Function instanceof Function`** is `true`.